# Close a program if file being read isn't formatted properly?

Tags: java, error-handling, assertions

My program reads a file the user chooses.
Edit: The file contains, a 4 character String, 4 digit int, and char (In that order) on one line, with an undisclosed number of lines.

If one of these is formatted wrong or missing the program need to provide a error message and close.

How would I go about checking for the errors?

Thanks.

Comment: @djechlin i have looked at assertions but I couldn't figure it out. My best would be to check for number of character for improper formatting. not sure what to do for if one is missing.

Comment: Well if one is missing "provide a error message and close," in your words.

Answer (score 0):

You can try parsing the content of the file within a try/catch bracket and if an exception is caught you display an error message and exit by with `System.exit(0)`;

```
try {
    //parsing
}
catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.prinln("Error message");
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your goal you should read yourself into *regular expressions* and *errorhandling* in java.

Then you can check your input weather it is formatted properly by using regular expressions and finaly, if you need to, throw a self-defined exception that tells everyone what happened.

[RegEx](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html)